# Как прокручивать окно при помощи WS_VSCROLL(C++ WINAPI)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

В своем оконном приложении на WINAPI решил использовать вертикальный скролл(Естественно, прописав в аргументах окна). Сам скролл появился, однако его прокрутка не дает никакого эффекта. Как реализовать прокрутку окна? Заранее благодарю

Comment: Обработчик на `WM_VSCROLL` повесили?

Comment: @VTT Нет, я поэтому и спрашиваю, как это реализовать, т.к сам не знаю

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/Controls/wm-vscroll                                                            И пример с скроллами https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/Controls/using-scroll-bars